# Modal is hiding automatically after showing another modal in vuejs.

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

> I am using `import bModal from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/modal/modal';` bootstrap-modal

I have following User Interface in Modal, here I need to choose department from a dropdown(getting item list using AJAX). Here I want to make it easy to add new department by clicking button beside the dropdonw - for such popup modal with UI. [image]

In vuejs i have code for main modal -

```
showModal () {
  this.clearForm();
  this.formInfo.formSubmitted = false;
  this.$refs[this.modalInfo.id].show();
}
```

this is working fine. Now on click event on green button, another modal should be opened over currently opened window. Unfortunately, currently modal is get hidden and new model opened. I have following code for extra modal-

```
showExtraModal:function(){
    this.$refs['extraModal'].show();
}
```

How can I solve this problem in vue js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a limitation of Bootstrap (see [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#how-it-works)):

> Bootstrap only supports one modal window at a time. Nested modals aren’t supported as we believe them to be poor user experiences.

Since `bootstrap-vue` is just a wrapper around Bootstrap, the same limitation will likely apply.

I had a similar problem with pure Bootstrap; IIRC I solved it by altering the content of the modal instead of showing a new one (in Vue-speak: rendering a different component), kind of a mini-routing inside the modal.

Comment: Hmm.. Yep, I also think of alternation but it seems like irritable UX and went for popovers. Thanks... for your reply. If you found my question is valuable please upvote it.